# Layout Swiping in Android with fixed button, How to?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having great trouble to implement layout swiping UI. Here I show you how each layout works.
My first Layout

[image]

My second layout

[image]

My third Layout

[image]

**How it works:** 
A user can move one page to another by touching the screen and the indicator will move as the layout or page move. But the Sign In and Sign Up button will be fixed in there position. How can I implement this type of UI.

Comment: better you can use tab

Comment: Is it possible to make an UI like that using tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a viewFlipper but there is a trick using this whole as a layout.

Use a frameLayout

having your buttons settled down with the gravity set to bottom

**Note framelayout works as a stack LIFO things(widgets/layouts) placed at last will superimpose the ones place above them in xml**

like for example

//so here view shows s2 and below that s1.....

so in your layout s2 will be the buttons with gravity as bottom
s1 -should be a **viewFlipper** ...

**SWIPPING**

swipping can be acheived using the onTouch event

- **SWIPE LEFT**

When the touch down gives a position(x1,y1) and onTouchUp (x2,y2)
check if(x2>x1)
so use viewFlipper.setInAnimation(Animation) viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(Animation)--for the ui that will be gone

- **SWIPE RIGHT**
  similarly if (x2<x1)

  viewFlipper.setInAnimation(Animation) viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(Animation)

Comment: I have to set image in viewFlipper.setInAnimation(animation image) but I want to swip layout not to set image. How to achieve it.

Comment: See the image you want to swipe is a also a subclass of View class , in simple words its infact a view only so setAnimation works on that too...so you can use setAnimation() on that view (THE BAR)....

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete example of `ViewFlow` please check out the source

https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow

and here is another example

http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/Animations.zip

see implementation of screen slide, that is what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

You have used three different layout and  increment counter  by touching the layout and match to set the layout.

Comment: But how to move the layout when user try to drag it.

Answer (score 0):

The bar moves something like this

```
Display d= getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int h=d.getHeight();
        int w=d.getWidth();
```

after getting this h and w , now at every swipe move the bar
where w=screen width calculated with the above method
increments=w/3;

bar_initial_position+=increments;

so it moves..